# GridView Bottom Overflowed by 4907 pixels

Tags: flutter, dart

I was writing the code for my application, but there's one part of the code which gives me problems. Specifically this one:

```
  List<Widget> _days() {
    List<Widget> widgets = [];
    for (int c = 0; c < 800; c++) {
      widgets.add(InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: dateColors[c],
          ),
          child: setDay(c),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            changeColors(c);
          });
        },
      ));
    }
    return widgets;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List months = [
      'JANUARY ',
      'FEBRUARY ',
      'MARCH ',
      'APRIL ',
      'MAY ',
      'JUNE ',
      'JULY ',
      'AUGUST ',
      'SEPTEMBER ',
      'OCTOBER ',
      'NOVEMBER ',
      'DECEMBER '
    ];
    int year = 2021;
    String yearStr = year.toString();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Calendar',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Center(child: Text(months[0] + yearStr))),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              GridView.count(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                crossAxisCount: 7,
                children: _days(),
              ),
              ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("Event 1"),
                  Text('Event 2'),
                  Text('Event 3'),
                  Text('Event 4'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

When I run it, it gives me this:

[image]

The problem doesn't appear if I use a smaller number of days in the GridView widget (in other words, a smaller number of iterations in the for loop). I'm trying to make it so that the GridView widget and the ListView widget scroll separately, but I haven't been successful so far. Does anyone know why?

EDIT: Both answers together solved the problem.

Comment: Just a tip, Don't put function/variables inside the `build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the Column with with this widget:

```
SingleChildScrollView
```

It should look like this after

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
     )
     )
```

This would make the Column scrollable

Comment: All errors disappeared, but I'm unable to actually scroll down.

Comment: @AndryCraft69 can you try the method below by adding NeverScrollableScrollPhysics

Answer (score 2):

Completing @Jesus Loves You method, add `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` to GridView:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GridView.count(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), //Here
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10,
            mainAxisSpacing: 2,
            crossAxisCount: 7,
            children: _days(),
          ),
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Event 1"),
              Text('Event 2'),
              Text('Event 3'),
              Text('Event 4'),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```